# Error when querying a CSV file

Tags: csv, asp-classic, ado

I have a server running Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0. My classic ASP application works perfectly there. I've been trying to get my application to work on IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008 in this new server provide that my company wants to migrate, however I've been struggling when querying a CSV file.

The code is the same in both enviroments, and while it works perfectly on my IIS 6 machine, it refuses to let me access my RecordSet generated by the query.

Here is the code:

```
Set conExcel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conExcel.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("xls\") &";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1; ImportMixedTypes=Text;FMT=Delimited(;)"""

strSQL="SELECT * FROM ["& strFile &"]"

set SQL = Server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")

SQL.Open strSQL,conExcel
```

The CSV file has several columns. One of them is called NAME.
The code to store it in a variable is the following:

```
strName = SQL("NAME")
```

The error I get only when running on IIS 7 is the classic "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal".
I couldn't find anything on the web related to changes in IIS 7 that would affect this feature. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: When you copied your csv file to the new server, was there a schema.ini file which needed to be moved over with it.  See here for further details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: No, there wasn't. The doc says it's not really not necessary. Unless you have some more complex data. Mine is just plain text. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a great battle I finally managed to make it work.

The query I posted in the above question works. The problem is how the recordset of a CSV file is accessed. Apparently, I can't call a column by writing SQL("NAME").

What I had to do was find another way to access the objects of the queries.
You can call the headers by typing 'SQL.Fields(0).Name'. It's an array, every iteration moves up to the next column. For the rows it's 'SQL.Fields(0).Value'.

The problem was I couldn't iterate the '.Value'. All the rows values were a giant string in the SQL.Fields(0).Value. I just had to split it passing the ';' symbol and voilá:

```
arrayCSV = split(SQL.Fields(0).Value,";")
```

Instead of calling SQL("NAME"), I just changed it to:

```
strName = arrayCSV(1)
strJob = arrayCSV(2)
```

and so on...

Hope this helps someone in the future. And I still don't know if this is an IIS 7 thing or a configuration somewhere on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your sql sentence to

```
strSQL = "SELECT [name] AS strName FROM ...."
```

And then the read sentence to

```
strName = SQL("strName")
```